# How to generate a list of repeating patterns from a string in TCL?

Tags: regex, split, tcl, inline

```
set s1 "dir1/dir2/some_word_g3_ger_another_word_g1_ger_TEMP2"
```

How to get this list {some_word_g3_ger_ another_word_g1_ger_} from s1 ?

I tried this :

```
regexp -inline -all {[^/]+_ger_} $s1
```

But it is failed to split :

`some_word_g3_ger_another_word_g1_ger`_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the match non-greedy, i.e. ensure that it ends *as soon as* it has found a minimal match, *not* when it has matched as much text as possible. This is done by using a `+?` quantifier (corresponding to the greedy `+` quantifier): in this case a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) is also necessary.

```
% regexp -inline -all {(?:[^/]+_ger_)+?} $s1
some_word_g3_ger_ another_word_g1_ger_
```

**ETA:**

A regular expression is helpful here since it can deal with both skipping the unwanted text *and* chopping up the tokens. If it is practicable to remove the unwanted text in a first step, several other methods become at least as useful. For example:

```
set s1 some_word_g3_ger_another_word_g1_ger_
string map {_ger_ {_ger_ }} $s1
```

(This results in the string "some_word_g3_ger_ another_word_g1_ger_ " with a trailing blank, but it is still functionally equivalent to the list of those two tokens.)

Documentation:
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: It's tempting to move the guard against slashes outside the match, but then you don't get the clean result you get here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another technique, using string commands:

```
set base [file tail $s1]
set start 0
while {1} { 
    set idx [string first _ger_ $base $start]
    if {$idx == -1} break
    lappend bits [string range $base $start $idx+4]
    set start [expr {$idx + 5}]
}
set bits
# => some_word_g3_ger_ another_word_g1_ger_
```